# ajax call redirect to page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my server terminal I saw Started GET "/another" but the browser dont redirect to the url. What is wrong in this code?

Routes:

```
match '/example_url', to: 'controllerx#sup', via: 'get'
```

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",// GET in place of POST
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "/example_url",
  data : {example: 'hey'},
  success: function(result) {
    //TODO
  },
  error: errorFunction
});
```

Controller:

```
def sup
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { redirect_to another_path }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You not able to redirect from the controller action because action called remotely.
Try this:

Client:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",// GET in place of POST
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/example_url",
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : {example: 'hey'},
  success: function(result) {
    window.location = result.location;
  },
  error: errorFunction
});
```

Controller:

```
def sup
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { location: another_path } }
   end
end
```

Comment: don't work "ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:"

Comment: my bad, I missing the respond to block